# How would our equations of thermodynamics change if we choose a non-linear interpolation for the kelvin scale?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

At [5:31 of this video](https://youtu.be/TDqx8Zv1rRo?t=328), professor Moungi Bawendi says that we could choose any kind of interpolation we like for the temperature scale, and all of thermodynamics would still be 'functionally' the same. This got me curious, for how the thermodynamic relations such as the ideal gas law and others would change as a consequence of this.

Comment: The answers would be equivalent, in the sense that the same physical predictions would be made, but the calculations would be harder. A bit like calculating the positions of the planets assuming Earth is the centre of the Solar System.

Comment: I'm interested in how the 'structure' of the equations would change

Comment: I think the only difference would be to replace T by f(T), where f is the conversion function from the new scale to the old.

Comment: @Peter Why not post as an answer?

Comment: That is an interesting comment.. setting up a one - one correspondence between scales, but I think it should be the inverse function $f(T)$ because the original gas law only exists in the linear kelvin scale?

Answer (score 0):

"Functionally the same" means that you would need to do slightly different Maths to get the same physical answer. There could be some formulas that would be simpler, but many (the ideal gas law for example) could only be made more complex. If $\tau$ represents temperature on the new scale and $T$ is temperature on the present scale we would be changing the ideal gas law from $$PV=nrT$$ to $$PV=nrf(\tau)$$ where $T=f(\tau)$ is the conversion function.

We actually do this already for the gas law when we change from Celsius (or even Fahrenheit) to Kelvin. Those formulas that only use $\Delta T$ can currently use Celsius without any change, but more complex changes would be needed for a more complex conversion function.